# Apache Refuses to Start when Enabling Second Site in Sites-Enabled/

Tags: apache, drupal, configuration

I've been trying for hours to get a newer sites configuration to work:

I have (2) site configuration files running on the same server, under:
`/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/site1` `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/site2`

if I do:

```
sudo a2dissite site2
sudo service apache2 reload
sudo service apache2 start
```

The server will show the content for `site1`

Now, if I enable `site1` and `site2` like:

```
sudo a2ensite site1
sudo a2ensite site2
sudo service apache2 reload
sudo service apache2 start
```

It will fail to start apache.

Here is site2 config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName site2.mysite.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite2
  LogLevel warn

  #Log Files
  ErrorLog /var/www/mysite2/logs/error.log
  CustomLog /var/www/mysite2/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<Directory /var/www/mysite2/>
  Options FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride all
  <FilesMatch "\.(engine|inc|info|install|module|profile|po|schema|sh|.*sql|theme|tpl(\.php)?|xtmpl)$|^(code-style\.pl|Entries.*|Repository|Root|Tag|Template)$">
    Order allow,deny
  </FilesMatch>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site2\.mysite\.org$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site2.mysite.com/$1 [L,R=301]

  #Rewrite URLs of the form 'index.php?q=x'.
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
</Directory>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue with the log file (and directory) not existing, in my case it was

```
/var/www/mysite2/logs/error.log
```

This was determined by errors being logged in the apache configuration at:

```
/var/log/apache2/error.log
```

Hope this helps someone in the future.